# Embedding multiple pages within one page, possible?

Tags: html, security, iframe, rss, embed

I wanted to make a webpage with three columns, one for my youtube feed, one for reddit, and one for a meme site undecided. I assumed this would be very simple using iframes, oh ho so wrong. I had no idea about the security google, facebook, reddit and others had taken to stop people from using iframes for their sites. Seeing no easy way to circumvent this issue I hope that the good people at stack overflow might have some knowledge of how I can do this.

Note, i also tried rss feeds. Found this very messy but if someone knows of a good way to do it please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use their API'S and convert the answer to your API reuqest to JSON so you can parse that as a video. That way you won't have to use iFrames. I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't even particularly want the video, just the subscription feed. Thank you though, I'll look into it

Comment: You can probably use the API to find those feeds. Facebook has a great tutorial on using their API and there's also tons of tutorials available on the internet! https://developers.facebook.com/

Comment: Google dev costs $25, I'm afraid I'm looking for a free option

Comment: As far as I know you can use their API's for free... Where are you getting that information from?

Comment: This is the page for using YouTube's api. I can not find anything about payment. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/ in what programming language do you want to display these feeds?

Comment: Hm, maybe where I was looking was false information. I was just going to use html originally with iframes. But I know a fair few languages

Comment: If you need any other information please ask, otherwise, if your question is satisfied, please mark the question as answered. Iframes are a really bad idea, don't use those :)

Comment: "All API requests, including invalid requests, incur at least a one-point quota cost. You can find the quota available to your application in the Developers Console." also at the top left of the dev console http://imgur.com/4citief